# How to create a module in Julia?

Tags: julia

I created this module

```
module MyModule
    export my_square, my_abs, my_minus
    my_square(x::Int64) = x * x
    my_abs(x) = (x>=0) ? x : -x
    my_add(x,y) = x + y
    my_minus(x,y) = x - y
    my_multiply(x,y) = x * y
end
```

but when importing it to use it it throws an error, any solution?

Answer (score 8):

This module got defined in the space of `Main` hence you need to add a dot `.` before module name:

```
julia> using .MyModule

julia> my_abs(-4)
4
```

Just note that `using Main.MyModule` will work as well just requires more typing.

If you want rather to write `using MyModule` (without a dot `.` nor `Main.`) you need to put that module into a Julia package. You will find a lot of documentation on creating packages but the simplest steps are:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.generate("MyModule")
```

In the folder src you will find `MyModule.jl`, edit it and paste the module definition.

Now you are ready to do:

```
julia> Pkg.activate(".\\MyModule") #use the correct path
    Activating environment at `MyModule\Project.toml`

julia> using MyModule
```